# In what sequence Model.save() and ModelForm.save() called

Tags: python, django

I understand that both `models.Model` and `forms.ModelForm` both contain `.save()` method that you can override. My question is how and when are they used to save an object and in what sequence.

Comment: Why don't you instrument them and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelForm.save()` is called first and it is calling `Model.save()` internally.

Method in `ModelForm` is an helper to build or update `Model` object from data provided in form and save it to database. It also saves any many to many or reversed foreign key relations.

Comment: Great. I looked up for `save()` method in `BaseModelForm` that `ModelForm` is inheriting  and found its calling `self.instance.save()` so your definitely right! Thanks